# Android TableLayout width issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I'm using TableLayout to display data.
Text of the TextViews of the right column will be set when activity calls onCreate().

Now, as you can see in the following image that my address text can be long and it should be wrapped.
So I set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`. but it still take a width of screen size to wrap data.
How can I overcome from this issue?

[image]

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5px">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="Job#"
            android:paddingRight="5px" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/DetailJobNo" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="Address"
            android:paddingRight="5px" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/DetailAddress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Address Address Address Address Address Address Address Address "/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `android:shrinkColumns="1"` to TableLayout solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting [setHorizontallyScrolling](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHorizontallyScrolling%28boolean%29) to the `DetailAdress` TextView to false?

Comment: Ok, looks like you have solved your problem! Cheers, indyfromoz

Answer (score 0):

@Vikas, its good that you have solved your problem.

BUt I would still recommend to use HorizontalScrollView for security purposes. If at all few chars are not visible, then horizontal scrollbar will help to manage that. XML text :

```
<HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
android:padding="5px">   
  ......
  ......
  ADD YOUR ROWS 
 </TableLayout>       
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Its always better to take care of the unexpected.