# layout_weight not honoured within TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to implement a 40% – 20% – 20% – 20% split (or something close to that) with four TextViews inside a TableLayout.

Problem is, the **leftmost column takes too much space**. In other words, the 3 columns on the right do not take the space they need. **The longer text on the left should be split on multiple lines if needed**, never the 3 shorter texts on the right.

[image]
<sup>The text marked with red should *not* be split on two lines.</sup>

I even tried `android:maxLines="1"` on the right-hand columns, and `android:lines="2"` on the leftmost column, and still it won't work as intented (→ there's just one line alright, but rightmost columns get clipped).

I also tried [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16903608/56285) and set `android:layout_width="0dp"` on the leftmost column. 
Well, that gives me the opposite problem: that column takes *too little* space (long titles get clipped), and the 3 on the right take too much.

[image]
<sup>Opposite problem with `android:layout_width="0dp"`</sup>

**I don't want to hardcode any DP width values** for the columns, to best support different screens. To me, specifying relative widths with `layout_weight` sounds exactly what I need, if only I got it working... Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**Android 4.4.2**. My test device is Nexus 7, on which I run into this problem in portrait mode.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Layout XML for one row (corresponding to the first screenshot above):

```
<TableRow
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="(todo)"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pages_read"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:maxLines="1"

        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:textSize="16dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        />

</TableRow>
```

Surrounding `TableLayout` and `ScrollView`:

```
 <ScrollView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <TableLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         <!-- table rows added dynamically in code -->

     </TableLayout>    
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I would suggest using a GridLayout (yes GridLayout not GridView) instead of the TableLayout.

Comment: Actually I found a simple solution while sticking with TableLayout: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20751799/56285

Comment: Learning to use GridLayout will make it worth your wile. It is more flexible than TableLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as is typical, I found the answer myself soon after asking here.

What I needed was:

```
android:shrinkColumns="0"
```

on the `TableLayout`. The **[`shrinkColumns`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#attr_android:shrinkColumns) attribute tells the layout which columns are eligible for shrinking**. (Zero-based index, so `0` means the leftmost column; you can specify several columns with comma as separator: `1, 2, 5`.)

I [**found the answer here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4623421/56285) (but I'm not sure if this qualifies as *exact* duplicate).

**Edit**: <s>I ended up throwing away all the `layout_weight` attributes from the TextViews as they didn't seem to have any effect.</s> Also `layout_width="wrap_content"` on the columns turned out unnecessary. Just `shrinkColumns="0"` on the layout does what I want.

**Edit 2**: Added back the `layout_weight`'s to each column (0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2) because otherwise *in landscape*, with plenty of room, the rows wouldn't use all the available horizontal space.

Answer (score 0):

Use this xml code:

```
<TableRow
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"

    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rating"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="(todo)"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pages_read"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:maxLines="1"

    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date_time"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:textSize="16dp"

    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    />

   </TableRow>
```